# Event when a user tries to navigate to a new URL via Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Basically, I want to make a chrome extension that reads the URL bar upon the user hitting enter and redirect them based on the contents.

Anyone know how to do this?

I'm reading through the API but can't find a method to read the URL on enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [WebRequest API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html). You can intercept changes based on all possible request resolve events in any window. See the documentation for details, but should be all you need.

Comment: I'm trying to use that but I'm struggling to get it to read raw input.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you mean you get the events but can parse the content? Or just can't even get the events to work?